# Can't build a Web Project in TeamCity

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, continuous-integration, teamcity, compass

I am using TeamCity as my CI server(mac).I am trying to build a web  project. When I use `grunt serve` or `grunt buildproduction` after changing directory to the cloned folder,it's working perfectly fine.But when I do this via TeamCity server it is giving an error `You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work`  and gets aborted due to warnings. Ruby and Compass is already installed in the server.Please help me on this.

```
rm -rf $(pwd)/node_modules/*
rm -rf $(pwd)/bower_components/*
npm cache clear
npm install
npm install bower
npm install grunt-ftp-push --save-dev
bower install
grunt buildproduction
```

This is the Command Line buildstep which I used in Teamcity..

Comment: Do you have agent installed on the same machine as server?

Comment: Yes...the problem was solved when I restarted my server..Thanks for the valuable time spent for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you probably use a different user or the shell environment is different (interactive vs non-interactive) when you run these commands manually and when it runs through TC it can't find those packages in the environment/PATH

Comment: Thanks Viktor Benei..Considering your suggestion I restarted my Server. Now TeamCIty is building the project for me...Thanks for your valuable time..

Comment: @Nevin Raj I'm glad that I could help :)